# Query on Windows Integrated Authentication for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please answer queries below on integrated authentication for SQL Server.

1. Does Windows authentication uses the client machine's user name and
   password to login to the SQL Server instance running on a server?
2. I read that the client should be in the same domain or trusted domain. What is trusted domain?
3. Should we need to add the client Windows username and
   password to SQL server so that it trusts the windows login of the
   client?

Comment: Those are statements, not questions. It would help if you actually phrase them as questions, to make it clear what precisely you are asking. Presumably you've already read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284(v=sql.100).aspx) on Windows authentication?

Comment: @Pondlife I have edited my question to give a more feeling like questions. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, but your questions have nothing to do with programming (and not much to do with SQL Server), so they're off-topic here: the [DBA site](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) and [sysadmin site](http://serverfault.com/) would probably give you better answers. Question 1 is answered in the documentation I linked to in my previous comment; 2 is a general Windows question that is also covered in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms722415(v=vs.85).aspx); 3 is asking about [creating logins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Windows Authentication uses the client's Security ID (SID). It does not transmit the password, ever, because that could be sniffed on the network by an attacker. Instead, it uses either Kerberos or NTLM to authenticate. Both use techniques to confirm that the user is validly logged on, without actually sending the password (or anything directly derived from the password) over the network.

See "[Understanding Kerberos and NTLM authentication in SQL Server Connections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/12/02/understanding-kerberos-and-ntlm-authentication-in-sql-server-connections.aspx)" for details of when each protocol is used. Normally both computers do need to be part of the same domain, or of domains that trust each other (in the same 'forest', for example). That page does imply that you can create the same Windows account on both ends even if the computers are not part of the same domain, or of trusted domains (under the heading *Login Failed for user ' ', the user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection*).